# Create 2 columns for a to-do list using enumerate and multicol

Tags: lists, multicol

[image]

I am trying to create a to-do list containing an enumerated list in one column. My MWE can be seen below. I would like to move the number of hours in brackets to be aligned with each new item (see image above). Thank you for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4]{article}


\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.} % default is "\theenumi."

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Title Text
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Very very very very very Long Text
            \item Normal text
            \item Normal text
        \end{enumerate} 
        
        \columnbreak

        \hfill (3h) \\
        \hfill (2h) \\
        \hfill (5.5h) \\

    \end{multicols}

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think, that `multicols` is suitable for this. Instead I suggest to use [package `enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to set a larger right margin for the list and to use a `\marginpar` to add the `(3h)` etc. into that additional margin:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}% Note: A4 would be an unknown an
                                     % therefore unused global option.

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*{\intextnote}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\makebox[0pt][r]{(#1)\hspace{\marginparsep}}}\ignorespaces}
  
\usepackage{showframe}% only for debugging to make the text area and other
                      % page areas visible
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for adding a lot of text easier

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Title Text
        \begin{enumerate}[rightmargin=5em]
            \item \intextnote{3h}\blindtext
            \item \intextnote{2h}Normal text
            \item \intextnote{5.5h}Normal text
        \end{enumerate} 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you'd replace `rightmargin=5em` by, e.g., `rightmargin=\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\columnsep\relax` the text column would be as narrow as in your example.